# ffmpeg seeking (-ss) not working past 13:15:20

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to pull a single frame every 30 minutes from a twitch VOD, but it only works up until I try to pull the frame at 13:30:00. It works just fine up until this timestamp.

The last timestamp it will work for is 13:15:20, 13:15:21 and after will not work.
When stuck it loops printing the following until I force stop it:

```
frame= 0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed= 0x
```

The exact one that fails is

```
ffmpeg -ss 13:30:00 -i https://d1ymi26ma8va5x.cloudfront.net/ad7df46d01d076a6cab0_ironmouse_44606619692_1644025354/chunked/index-muted-FMTK8V9QQ2.m3u8 -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 OutputFile_27.jpeg
```

I've tried other links and it also fails in the same spot.

What's causing this error, is there a way to get it to work? (Or a much better way to do this in general)

Comment: Based on what do you conclude that "it fails"? Is there any error message?

Comment: It doesn't output any files. Looking at the cmd it seems to be stuck in a loop with a every value set to either 0 or N/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works fine on v5.0. Update if you aren't using the latest (master/release). Otherwise, perhaps a better approach is to read .ts file directly. If you look inside the .m3u8 (text) file, it lists a whole bunch of .ts files (the one you linked has a .ts file for every 10 seconds. e.g.,

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#ID3-EQUIV-TDTG:2022-02-06T04:18:26
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TWITCH-ELAPSED-SECS:0.000
#EXT-X-TWITCH-TOTAL-SECS:95519.004
#EXTINF:10.000,
0.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
1.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
2.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
3.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
4.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
5.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
6.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
7.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
8.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
9.ts
#EXTINF:10.000,
10.ts
...
#EXTINF:10.000,
9549.ts
#EXTINF:4.978,
9550.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

30 minutes is 1800 seconds, which means you need to snag the first frame every 180 files off

```
ffmpeg -i https://d1ymi26ma8va5x.cloudfront.net/ad7df46d01d076a6cab0_ironmouse_44606619692_1644025354/chunked/0.ts \
       -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 OutputFile_00.jpeg

ffmpeg -i https://d1ymi26ma8va5x.cloudfront.net/ad7df46d01d076a6cab0_ironmouse_44606619692_1644025354/chunked/180.m3u8 \
       -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 OutputFile_01.jpeg

...

ffmpeg -i https://d1ymi26ma8va5x.cloudfront.net/ad7df46d01d076a6cab0_ironmouse_44606619692_1644025354/chunked/9540.ts \
       -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 OutputFile_53.jpeg
```

This will relieve you from reading the .m3u8 file every time and no need to seek.

Comment: Just updated, works now. Will try reading the .ts. Are those in the format "... chunked/[n].ts"?

Comment: Saw you just checked this answer. Have you figured out the .ts url? You got it right for this m3u8 file, but better to check each stream for their ts file naming and durations.

Comment: Ah yes it works just fine. Used that without issue for the rest of them